# Improving query speed (subquery + Join)

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I'm querying a database with transaction details, where each transaction goes through multiple steps in its lifecycle (e.g. received, pending, processed). I need to return all transaction IDs that have ever been associated with 'Purch', and then return only the last step in that transaction's individual life cycle.

The below query returns what I expect, but the run time (~15 minutes) leaves a lot to be desired. The table I'm working with has a few million records.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Sample table data:

| TransactionID | Company | Order Type | Status | StepCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Company A | Purch | Received | 01/01/2023 |
| 12345 | Company A | Redeem | Processed | 01/02/2023 |
| 12225 | Company C | Purch | Received | 01/01/2022 |
| 12345 | Company A | Redeem | Reviewed | 01/05/2023 |
| 22345 | Company B | Purch | Received | 01/10/2023 |
| 44444 | Company A | Purch | Received | 02/01/2023 |
| 44444 | Company A | Redeem | Processed | 02/02/2023 |
| 55555 | Company A | Purch | Received | 05/01/2023 |
| 55555 | Company A | Purch | Processed | 05/02/2023 |

I want to return...

| TransactionID | Company | Order Type | Status | StepCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Company A | Redeem | Reviewed | 01/05/2023 |
| 44444 | Company A | Redeem | Processed | 02/02/2023 |
| 55555 | Company A | Purch | Processed | 05/02/2023 |

Query which does return data as expected - but it's slow:

```
Select 
    * 
From 
    (Select 
         A.TransactionID, 
         Company, 
         OrderType, 
         Status, 
         Row_Number() over (partition by A.TransactionID 
                            order by StepCount desc) as RecordNo 
     From 
         OrderTable as A 
     Inner Join 
         (Select 
              TransactionID 
          From 
              OrderTable 
          Where 
              Company = 'Company A' 
              And OrderType = 'Purch') as B on A.TransactionID = B.TransactionID 
     Group By 
         A.TransactionID, Company, OrderType, Status) as Data 
Where 
    Data.RecordNo = 1
```

Comment: Performance questions require an execution plan using "paste the plan" and all table and index definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that using a lateral join could be much faster, if paired with a couple of indexes.

You can try:

```sql
select y.*
from (
  select distinct transactionid
  from ordertable 
  where order_type = 'Purch'
) x
cross apply (
  select top 1 *
  from ordertable o
  where o.transactionid = x.transactionid
  order by stepcount desc
) y
```

Using the indexes:

```sql
create index ix1 on ordertable (order_type) include (transactionid);

create index ix2 on ordertable (transactionid, stepcount);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with dataX as (
    select *,
        first_value(firstOrderType) over (partition by TransactionId order by StepCount) as firstOrderType,
        first_value(Status) over (partition by TransactionId order by StepCount) as firstStatus,
        first_value(StepCount) over (partition by TransactionId order by StepCount) as firstStepCount,
        min(case when Status = 'Purch' then 1 end) as hasPurch
    from T
    where CompanyName = 'X'
)
select distinct
    CompanyName, TransactionId, 
    firstOrderType, firstStatus, firstStepCount
from dataX
where hasPurch = 1;
```